# svmlight / libsvm format

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new with programming.  I am trying to prepare a file for scikit leaner and I want to convert my txt file or excel file into a file with svmlight / libsvm format.  Is it possible to obtain a format  : : using a txt file as input with a python application ?

Comment: The answer is Yes. Show us what have you tried till now.

Comment: My csv file has 80 columns, first column = name, second column = class and rest of the columns are features.  there are 5 classes in the data set and I am planning to use the following but I am not sure if this is correct. import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import datasets, svm
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_fileload_svmlight_files"sequencefeature.csv",  multilabel = True, zero_based = False)

Comment: I need to put this file on the scikit learner package and I am not sure about the input file and I want to confirm if my csv file is suitable for that script